# How to read CSV data by matching the input in java?

Tags: java, csv

Trying to create a program where the user is asked to enter a location, if the user enters i.e south it can read from the "Location" column in the csv, and whatever row contains "south" (upper or lowercase accepted), the name(s) from the Name column are printed. So if the user enters south, Holos and Deafer are returned.

I can't seem to find how to actually print specific rows that contains matching input, and have only been able to print the whole column.

Any help is much appreciated!

Csv

```
Name, Location
Holos, South
Tredies, North
Warren, West
Deafer, South
```

Current code that only reads specific column

```
    public void filter() {
        // using buffered reader to read the csv file, still a WIP
        String path = "E:\\IT\\2022\\Further Programming\\s3902169_furtherProgrammingA1\\src\\files\\Melbnb.csv";
        String line = "";

        System.out.println("Enter location");
        String stringInput = readUserInput();

        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");

                if (stringInput.contains(values[1])) {
                    System.out.print(values[0]);
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: The line `if (stringInput.equals(stringInput))` should look suspicious to you.

Comment: I definitely know that's wrong, I have no clue what I should be doing from here and hope to get some guidance.

Comment: `String[] values` is an array that holds e.g. `Holos` and `South` in it. So the first element of `values` is what you want to compare to `stringInput`.

Comment: Aside from the error in your code which I believe the first comment above addresses, I'd suggest using Apache Commons CSV Reader or another library.  CSV has issues with embedded commas, quotes etc.  Much easier to rely upon a library that has gone through those hassles than write your own. 

In your example, it's pretty easy to parse, however what if you had the following line in the CSV file:   "Las Santos", North

Comment: @CraigTaylor how would that line mess up splitting at a comma?

Comment: @f1sh i've gone ahead and changed the code, please take a look at the update. However this only prints one value with the specific keyword. I wish to print every row that contains the string from the location column, so if I were to enter "Sou", it'll still output everything that contains "Sou" - which should still output Holos and Deafer.

Comment: values[1] is the full word. You want to check if _that_ word contains the input. _NOT_ the other way around (input contains the full word)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase(values[1)) {
        System.out.println(values[0]);
 }
```

Comment: You probably want to trim() it also

Comment: Yes right on both.

Comment: Tried this, however the user input is pretty much locked to the specific keyword entered - how do I change it so that if I were to enter "Sou", it'll still output everything that contains "Sou". I am planning to add more data, hence my question.

Comment: then converting both to lower case might help,

`if (stringInput.trim().toLowerCase().contains(values[1].trim().toLowerCase())) 
`

Comment: It should be opposite,

`if (values[1].trim().toLowerCase().contains(stringInput.trim().toLowerCase()))`